# Keep the new line symbols in the string when writing in a text file Python

Tags: python, io, newline

I have a list of strings, and some of the strings contain '\n's. I want to write this list of strings into a text file and then later on read it back and store it to a list by using `readlines()`. I have to keep the original text; meaning not removing the new lines from the text.

If I don't remove all these new lines then of course `readlines()` will return a larger number of strings than the original list.

How can I achieve this? Or there's really no way and I should write in other formats instead. Thanks.

Comment: So what do you want? Do you want to remove newlines or keep them?

Comment: You could write the strings' `repr` and then `eval` (or `ast.literal_eval`) the lines when reading them back in... or just replace the newlines with some "magic string", like, `'NEWLINE'`.

Comment: Are you sure? Neither `write` nor `writelines` adds newlines. Are you adding any yourself?

Comment: You could use the fact that \ is an escape character for itself, so `\\n` will be written as `\n`.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan - but then its not a newline any more.

Comment: @blue482 - are you trying to keep the list boundaries? `pickle` and `json` would be good choices.

Comment: @tdelaney I was under the impression that the asker wanted to keep it the '\n's as literal '\n's, but rereading I think you're right and they do want them as newline characters.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I'm still not sure what OP wants!

Answer (score 2):

The following:

```
from __future__ import print_function
strings = ["asd", "sdf\n", "dfg"]
with open("output.txt", "w") as out_file:
  for string in strings:
    print(repr(string), file=out_file)
with open("output.txt") as in_file:
  for line in in_file:
    print(line.strip())
```

prints

```
'asd'
'sdf\n'
'dfg'
```

To print it normally (without the quotes), you can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval): `print(ast.literal_eval(line.strip()))`